# Testing views with 'logged in user' without accessing database

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have written som arbitrary code to test a view-class with and without a logged in user. However, while doing that I have to create a user, which accessed the database. To follow good practice for TDD unittests I would try to avoid accessing the database, but I don't know how

I've briefly tried to patch different modules, but I haven't figured out exactly how or what to patch

This is the solution I'm using today:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestTreaterProfile:
    """
    get with anonymous
    get with logged-in user
    """
    [...]

    def test_get_with_logged_in_user(self):
        status_code = [200]
        view_class = ClientProfile

        client = Client()
        user = User.objects.create_user("user", "my@email.com", "password")
        client.force_login(user)

        # create request and retrieve response
        request = RequestFactory().get("/")
        request.user = user
        response = view_class.as_view()(request, *[], **{})

        assert response.status_code in status_code, "Should have status_code 200 - OK"
```

The code works, I would just like to modify it so that it don't have to access the database.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the user in the test's `setUp` method ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/)), so that you don't pollute your actual test method (as that's what I'm assuming you're trying to avoid). FYI: this still hits the database.

```py
class TestTreaterProfile:
    ...
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user("user", "my@email.com", "password")
    ...
    def test_get_with_logged_in_user(self):
        ...
        request.user = self.user
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `forcing_authentication()`

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication